# How to replace the line catch by bash script read line?

Tags: shell-script

I have a set of configuration files and i want to comment out some configuration in all file in a directory that contains that configuration line in theme.

Configuration file looks like this:

```
...
someconfig = comand()#@#$#$@#
             asdbaksdjbkajsbd
             asdasdjhavshdjvas
...
```

so i decided to use bash script to do that

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='myconfigfile.conf'
echo Start ...
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^someconfig.* ]]; then
        echo "$line"
        sed -i 's/$line/\#\$line/g' $filename 
    fi
done < $filename
```

The prefered output line in that file :

```
...
#someconfig = comand()#@#$#$@#
#             asdbaksdjbkajsbd
#             asdasdjhavshdjvas
...
```

I did that in python ,but i want to see if it is possible in bash script without complicating it too much.

I have a solution for detecting next line start with a non space char by using a boolean and iterationg through all files to change those line in all files, but i don't know what to do with replacing part and my code dos not seems to be working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou thank you for your help, I tried it , it didn't work.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou , the problem is , this script, dos not effect the config file at all. it just print the line that start with someconfig.

Comment: This command , works ok in my tests without loop: `sed -E 's/(^[ ]*.*)/#\1/g' file1`. This will give you the output you want. If you encounter a different problem , then your question needs to be rephrased in order to express your real problem.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou this command , comment out everything not just that config line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation in the question is problematic and inefficient.

You read the file line by line and construct an `sed` command from an input line. This command may behave unexpectedly if the line contains any regex special characters like `.^$[]` etc.

Then you process the whole file with `sed` once for every line that has to be changed. You could process every line individually instead of repeatedly processing the whole input file.

I propose to use `awk` to process the file and use a shell script wrapper that handles the temporary output file. (`awk` does not support in-place editing like `sed` or `perl`.)

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='myconfigfile.conf'

temp=${filename}.temp

awk '/^[^   ]/ { comment=0 }     # stop commenting if line starts with non-space.
     /^someconfig/ { comment=1 } # start commenting if line starts with "someconfig"
     comment {$0 = "#" $0}       # prepend "#" to whole line ($0)
     { print }' $filename > $temp && mv -f $temp $filename || rm -f $temp
```

You could optionally add a rule

```
     /^[    ]*$/ { comment=0 }   # stop commenting on empty line or space only
```

to stop commenting when an empty line or a line containing only whitespace occurs.

Note that `[^   ]` and `[   ]` contain one space and one tab character.

The script doesn't **detect** any indentation. It simply prepends `"#"` to whatever is in the line (including the indentation) as long as `comment` is nonzero.

Comment: Thanks, It actually works , one question though , How it detect the indent of the next line of the configuration? could you please explain comment {$0 = "#" $0}` line ? what $0 means ?

Comment: `$0` is awk for "the whole current line". So that replaces the whole line with a comment char and then the line. The print at the end then prints whatever is in `$0` when it's called.

Answer (score 0):

Why use sed or awk if you're already processing the file line by line in the shell? Something like this would work without having to use a bunch of other programs.

```
[[ $line =~ '^[[:space:]]' ]] || indent=0
if [[ $line =~ ^someconfig.* || $indent ]]
then
    echo -n "#"
    indent=1
fi
echo "$line"
```

Send the loop output to a temp file and then `mv` as in the (also very good) awk answer:

```
done <$file >$file.tmp && mv $file.tmp $file
```

I generally prefer the rename to be linked with && so it won't happen if the command fails. Also, sorry for any typos - I'm typing this on a phone, and it's hard to write code on a phone keyboard. :)